# To select hidden values from dropdown C# webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

I have an issue in selecting a drop down value in C# webdriver. I am getting an error message saying it is an invisible element.I researched on accessing hidden elements in Web driver ,C# but was unable to find a workable solution. So far , I have tried the Actions method and Java script Executor but not sure what I am doing wrong. I am pretty new to Automation and using the C# language.

This is my below code using Actions method

```
IWebElement actionsMenu = driver.FindElement(By.Id("InitiatorID"));
Actions action = new Actions (driver);
action.MoveToElement(actionsMenu).Build().Perform();      
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[index ='2']")).Click();**/
```

Script Using Java script Executor

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)wd).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].Click()");
wd.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@value = Bridget]"));
String("arguments[0].trigger('click')");
wd.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@value = Bridget]"));
```

I am new to Java Script as well, I am not sure if the syntax is incorrect. 
This is the HTML

```
<div class="question">
   <label for="InitiatorID">Initiator:</label>
   <div id="InitiatorID_chzn" class="chzn-container chzn-container-single" style="width: 270px;">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="chzn-single" tabindex="-1">
         <span>Not Assigned</span>
      </a>
      <div class="chzn-drop" style="left: -9000px; width: 268px; top: 24px;">
         <div class="chzn-search">
            <input type="text" autocomplete="off" style="width: 233px;" tabindex="-1">
         </div>
         <ul class="chzn-results">
            <li id="InitiatorID_chzn_o_0" class="active-result result-selected" style="">Not Assigned</li>
      </div>
```

Can somebody please help in solving this issue. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is an unorderlist category dropdown where the values will be visible only after clicking on it. The solution i suggest is first find the element where you need to click. And use element.click. Manuall see the html code of the UL and LI tags when you clicked on the element.Definitely you can see the html code to identify the UL and LI.Capture all LI tags and iterate through each value and perform click on it.There are many threads running on the same issue. Please google.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it helps but let me try anyway:

First of all, selenium webdriver is basically for automating stuff you can do manually. Manually you can't click on a hidden element, so with selenium you can't either. Probably, if manually you can select that value there's some steps you do like clicking to open a dropdown-menu, or as Parker Beck suggests hovering over an element in order to open a dropdown menu. Then once the element is visible and active, you can click it. 
With selenium you have to automate all the same steps.

And maybe, the answer is a bit simpler: it could be that after moving to the element `action.MoveToElement(actionsMenu).Build().Perform();` you have to wait a bit before you click or webdriver is going to be too fast!
There's many ways to wait, just search a bit and you'll find a bunch of topics on that!

Edit after reading your comment below:
action.MoveToElement(actionsMenu).Build().Perform();==> only moves the mousepointer. It does not click it, so your next element will not be visible. If you require to click 2 times manually, your selenium code should also click two times. From what I understand so far, you may miss the first click.

Comment: I disagree that "This does not provide an answer to the question. " - it does.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're making things too complicated. There shouldn't be a need to manually move over the element using actions. Can you try the following?

```
//Find the dropdown container and click it
IWebElement actionMenu = driver.FindElement(By.Id("InitiatorID"));
actionMenu.Click(); //Feel free to condense this to just driver.FindElement().Click();

//Find the now visible option and click it
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@value = Bridget]")).Click();
```

Comment: If it's a menu that expands on hover instead then that's different, I might've misinterpreted the question. Just let me know and I'll try to change it.

Comment: Hello Chai/Parker, The manual actions involved are , Click on a drop down and then click on a value from the drop down. So my code does not even click on the drop down as of now because the display is none .

Comment: `SelectElement` only works on SELECT tags. This is one of those cases where the dropdown isn't actually a `SELECT` tag so this code won't work.

Comment: @JeffC Yeah, I see that now, I wrote this before he added the included html. @Kalaivani Can you click the actionsMenu then do `driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[index ='2']")).Click();`?

Comment: Hello, Thank you all for the inputs. I was able to click on the hidden drop down with the below code, but then I was not able to select  a value from drop down. I tried the below code                                          IWebElement actionsMenu = driver.FindElement(By.Id("XXXX"));
             Actions action = new Actions (driver);
             action.MoveToElement(actionsMenu).Build().Perform();
             actionsMenu.Click();
            SelectElement menu = new SelectElement(actionsMenu);
            menu.SelectByValue("Bridget );

Comment: With tthe above code, I got an exception saying "Unable to Locate an Element" when searched for the value Bridget. I am still researching on it , any inputs will be helpful.

Comment: @Kalaivani I edited my answer to reflect what I believe the code should be. Can you try this and tell me if it works?

Comment: Hi Parker, I tried the above code to click the visible option and it did not work out. I got an exception saying, " no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@value = 'Bridget']"}

Comment: @Kalaivani Is that a valid xpath to the correct option? I snagged that from your Javascript approach. Does `By.CssSelector("[index ='2']")` work instead?

Comment: Hi Parker, thanks for looking into it. To answer your question the xpath option is correct. also i used  this below code and i got element is not currenlty visible and may not be manipulated.                              IWebElement value = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='InitiatorID']/option[2]"));
 value.Click(); I tried the same with the Actions method as well, didnt work